# Most efficient way to create a writable anonymous scalar/string?

Tags: perl

What is the best way to create/allocate an anonymous writable scalar/string?  There's a paragraph in the `perlref` doc:

```
*foo{THING} returns undef if that particular THING hasn't been used yet,
except in the case of scalars. *foo{SCALAR} returns a reference to an
anonymous scalar if $foo hasn't been used yet. This might change in a
future release.
```

That is unreliable though. If there exists `$foo` in the package, the result is no longer an anonymous reference.

Alternative methods I've tried:

```
my $ref=\"";      #Reference to a literal. NOT writable of course

my $ref=\("".""); #Concatenation of two empty strings. 

my $ref=\(""x0);  #String repeat zero times

my $ref=\join("",("",));

sub newString{
    my $string="";
    \$string;
}

my $ref=newString();    #Ref from lexical in sub
```

**Updated benchmarking with responses:**

My (over simplistic?) benchmark:

```
cmpthese(10000000,
    {
    concat=>sub { my $ref=\(""."");},
    repeat=>sub { my $ref=\(""x0);},
    sub=>sub { my $ref=newString},
    join=>sub {my $ref=\join("","")},
    auto=>sub {my $ref; $$ref="";},
    do=>sub {my $ref=do{\ (my $x = "") }}
}
```

Gives:

```
             Rate concat   join repeat    sub     do   auto
concat  7633588/s     --    -2%    -6%    -6%   -37%   -55%
join    7812500/s     2%     --    -4%    -4%   -35%   -54%
repeat  8130081/s     7%     4%     --    -0%   -33%   -52%
sub     8130081/s     7%     4%     0%     --   -33%   -52%
do     12048193/s    58%    54%    48%    48%     --   -29%
auto   16949153/s   122%   117%   108%   108%    41%     --
```

The do method (do above) is also very quick in comparison! Thanks choroba.
I'm assuming the autovivication (auto above) is how zdim's answer works. I didn't even consider that way! Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with `my \$foo`?

Comment: What's wrong with `my $ref;` ... and _then_ make it a reference, like `$$ref = q(hi); say $$ref`?

Comment: Ahh thats much better.

Comment: do is faster than sub `do=>sub {my $ref=do{\ (my $x = "") }}`

Comment: Re "**I'm assuming the autovivication (auto above) is how zdim's answer works*", Yes

Comment: Why sub or do? Just `my $ref=\(my $x = "")` would do. Don't need their overhead

Comment: @ikegami, using `do` ensures that the scope of `$x` doesn't leak. `do` does have the overhead of setting up and tearing down a lexical scope, but that's pretty small.

Comment: @tobyink 1. There's already a scope in the test. 2. There would already be a scope in practice. 3. `do` makes a copy of the scalar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way: just introduce the symbol, and make it the desired type on use

```
my $ref;
...
$$ref = q(word);
```

Comment: Can also change the type later, `$ref = [1..2];` ...